# Which of the sets are equal?

Tags: analysis, complex-numbers

Which of these sets are equal?

$A= \{ z \in \mathbb{C}; \frac{1}{z}+\frac{1}{\overline{z}}\leq2\}$ ---------> $x^2-x+y^2 \geq 0 $

$B= \{ z \in \mathbb{C}; \frac{1}{z}+\frac{1}{\overline{z}}< 2\}$ ---------> $x^2-x+y^2 > 0 $

$C= \{ z \in \mathbb{C}; |z-\frac{1}{2}|\geq\frac{1}{2}\}$ ---------> $x^2-x+y^2 \geq 0 $

$D= \{ z \in \mathbb{C}; |z-\frac{1}{2}|>\frac{1}{2}\}$ ---------> $x^2-x+y^2 > 0 $

---

Well, I tried to solve this problem by writing in Cartesian coordinates (look above). The the solution manual only states "B = D. No other pair is equal."

Why are A and C not equal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $0\in C$ but $0\notin A$.